# Busting CLT - What is a better approximation for the sample-mean distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, weak-convergence

Central limit theorem states that, for any population with finite mean and variance, if the sample size goes to infinity, then the distribution of sample mean (weakly) converges to normal distribution.

I think two equally important theorems are very similar to CLT. One is Sterling theorem for approximating factorials. The other is the prime-approximation theorem. For both of them, better approximation exists, and some of the better approximations are discovered in the recent 30 years.

However, when I am doing a literature search, I find no better approximation than CLT. I find it super abnormal. My intuition is that constructing a new approximation is not impossible. Normal distribution is not the best possible approximation. Am I correct?

Comment: Your question does not quite make sense to me, but see Berry Esseen

Comment: If you start with iid normal distributions, the sums and means still have normal distributions.  If you start with iid Poisson distributions (or binomial distributions), their sums still have Poisson (or binomial) distributions (and their means rescaled Poisson/binomial distributions) but for high parameter values their (rescaled relocated) CDFs get "closer" to that of a normal distribution with the same mean and variance.  So in some specific cases we can state the distribution precisely, but there is no general "better approximation".

Comment: How about Edgeworth expansions?

Comment: @Henry Then, is it possible to prove that Normal distribution is the best approximation in general if we don't know the population?

Comment: @kimchilover That's so great!